# Gunicorn, Flask Server, Nginx: Timeout Error

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, wsgi

I'm currently trying to connect to a flask server running with gunicorn from outside the local network through a reverse proxy with nginx but I get Timeout errors every time I'm trying to connect.

So here's my setup:

Flask file:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Then I'm starting it with Gunicorn like this:
[image]

netstat lists the process:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16664/python3
```

The reverse proxy setup in Nginx (path: /etc/nginx/sites-available/flaskSrv) looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 5000;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/accesslog.log

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /;
    }
  }
```

But if I'm trying to connect to https://example.com:5000/ I get an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Same with http://example.com:5000/

I'm pretty sure my flask file is correct and think there is something wrong with Nginx.

Edit: I solved the problem by calling a PHP script from JS ajax and calling the python script from PHP via `system`

Answer (score 0):

I think you run gunicorn at 127.0.0.1 that listen at local network. Try change to 0.0.0.0 `listen on every available network interface` and run again

Comment: I already tried that still doesn't work. Also, I want it to listen to the local network that's why I made the reverse proxy.